# How can disable autofill for username in html?

Tags: html

I have code to prevent password to autofill from browser, but I can not still prevent it for username textbox on the HTML page.
Here is the code for the password field on the page.

```
enter code here


   <input type="text" name="abc" id="abc">
    <style>
    -webkit-text-security:desc;
    </style>
```

Here this code makes my textbox looks alike as the password field, and it's working fine. Even browser doesn't ask for save passwords.

Please suggest me guys for username.

Comment: <style>
    -webkit-text-security:desc;
    </style>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you disable browser Autocomplete on web form field / input tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530/how-do-you-disable-browser-autocomplete-on-web-form-field-input-tag)

Comment: I had seen it, but that is for autocomplete disable. My questions is for Autofill. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Autocomplete allows the browser to predict the value. When a user starts to type in a field, the browser should display options to fill in the field, based on earlier typed values.

Note: The autocomplete attribute works with the following  types: text, search, url, tel, email, password, datepickers, range, and color.

```
<input type="text" name="test" autocomplete="off" />
```

Still there are some facts you need to know about this attribute , those are as below:

1. Firefox 30 ignores autocomplete="off" for passwords, opting to prompt the user instead whether the password should be stored on the client.
2. The password manager always prompts if it wants to save a password. Passwords are not saved without permission from the user.
3. According to Mozilla developer documentation the form element attribute autocomplete prevents form data from being cached in older browsers.
4. Also some chrome extensions also on automcomplete it self so when your testing this attribute just make sure you disable those extensions.

Comment: No, it's not working for me. Autocomplete="off" gives no suggestion while typing in the textbox, but when you double-click on the textbox it shows saved passwords and username in browsers.

Comment: @SachinHegadepatil, Uhm so did you find a solution?